# solving second order non-homogeneous differential equation 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem on solving this differential equation.
$
y=c_{1}+c_{2}e^{-2x}-cos2x-1/2(sin2x-cos2x)
$ 
I reached :
$
y''+2y'=4sin2x
$

as answer but I'm not sure.
my step by step solution is :

$
y_{h}=c_{1}+c_{2}e^{-2x}
$

$
w(1,e^{-2x})=-2e^{-2x}
$

$
u_{1}=\int([-e^{2x}*4sin2x]/-2e^{-2x})=> u_{1}=-cos2x
$

$
u_{2}=\int(4sin2x/-2e^{-2x})=> u_{2}=-1/2e^{2x}(sin2x-cos2x)
$

$
y_{p}=-cos2x-1/2e^{2x}(sin2x-cos2x)
$

$
y=c_{1}+c_{2}e^{-2x}-cos2x-1/2e^{2x}(sin2x-cos2x)
$

Comment: Of cource that is wrong answer

Comment: is it not easier to solve the first order equation for $y'?$

Comment: Can anyone please tell me which part of my solution is wrong??

Answer (score 1):

your solution must be $$y \left( x \right) =-1/2\,\sin \left( 2\,x \right) -1/2\,\cos \left( 2
\,x \right) -1/2\,{{\rm e}^{-2\,x}}{\it \_C1}+{\it \_C2}
$$
the nonhomogeneous part must have the form $$A\sin(2x)+B\cos(2x)$$

Comment: doctor can you please write the answer step by step....

Answer (score 1):

Taking a quick look at the right hand side of the equation, you can tell that the method to be used is that of **Undetermined Coefficients**.

The first steps in solving a differential equation of this type follows other methods we have solved so far, that is start by solving for the roots of the characteristic equation of the associated homogeneous solution. This goes as follows:

$$m^2 + 2m = 0$$
$$m(m+2) = 0$$

meaning that you have 2 distinct real roots.

$m_1 = 0$
$m_2 = -2$

$\implies y_h = c_1e^{0x} +c_2e^{-2x} =  c_1 + c_2e^{-2x} $

The second step is using the method of undetermined coefficient. By looking at the LHS of the equation, we can conjecture that the particular solution is of the form:

$y_p = A\sin(2x) + B\cos(2x)$

There are no duplicates in the homogeneous solution so no multiplicity, which means we can carry on.

$\implies$
$y_p' =2Acos(2x) -2Bsin(2x) $

$\implies$
$y_p'' =-4Asin(2x) -4Bcos(2x) $

Plug this in the equation to find A and B.

$$-4Asin(2x) -4Bcos(2x) +4Acos(2x) -4Bsin(2x) = 4sin(2x)$$
$$(-4A - 4B)sin(2x) + (-4B +4A)cos(2x) = 4 sin(2x)$$

This means that

\begin{cases} -4A -4B = 4 \\ -4B +4A = 0 \end{cases}

Thus $A = B = -\frac{1}{2}$

Finally since $y= y_p + y_h$ we get:

$$y = c_1 + c_2e^{-2x} -\frac{1}{2}[sin(2x) + cos(2x)]$$

Comment: wait..why $m^{2}+2=0$??? I thought It should be $m^{2}+2m=0$

Comment: You are entirely correct, I fixed it but a bit late!

Comment: excuse me but I didn't get this point : $y_{p}=Asin(2x)+Bcos(2x)$ I only know $w(y_{1},y_{2})$ method to solve such equation and by that method I reach to another answer...(please explain that line)

Comment: I think you can use the wronskian to solve this, however $w(y_1, y_2)$ is used for complicated particular solutions that cannot be solved using the method I used above.

Comment: if you consider at my answer which I typed above..you will see it's almost the same but with one more $-cos2x$ it came from my wronskian method because of : $u_{1}=-cos2x$

Comment: Edit your OP and show your work, I will see where you went wrong.

Comment: my solution step by step is ready...

Answer (score 0):

i think it is easier to solve the equation for $y'.$ so let $u = y'.$ then $u$ satisfies $$u' + 2u = 4\sin 2x\tag 1$$ the homogeneous solution is $$u_h = -2ce^{-2x} $$ trying a particular solution of the form $$u = a\cos 2x + b \sin 2x, u' = -2a\sin 2x + 2b \cos 2x  \tag 2$$  subbing $(2)$ in $(1),$  we have $$(-2a+2b)\sin 2x + (2b +2a)\cos 2x=4 \sin 2x $$ so that we can set $$-2a + 2b = 4, 2a + 2b = 0\to b = 1, a = -1 $$ giving $$u_p = \sin 2x - \cos 2x $$

the general solution is $$ u = y' = -2ce^{-2x} + \sin 2x - \cos 2x \tag 3 $$

integrating $(3)$ gives $$y = ce^{-2x}-\frac12 \cos 2x -\frac12\sin 2x + d $$ where $c,d$  are arbitrary constants.

Comment: we have almost similar 4 answer but with a little bit differences

Comment: @sajjad, what do you mean almost?

Comment: I got a only one $-cos2x$ more which I don't know why you don't have....

Comment: @sajjad, your particular solution with $e^{2x}(\sin 2x - \cos 2x)$ is not right.